# Should I mix queries in for LSH index building

Tags: knn, locality-sensitive-hash

When I read the Multiprobe LSH and the Multiprobe LSH performance tuning paper, I found in their experiments, the queries were randomly chosen from the dataset for index building.
Is it a must to do so?
Can LSH handle the unseen points query?